# Tickera plugin Wordpress modify default form

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am using Tickera plugin. The page which shows the tickets it's at example.com/tickets-cart/ . This page has a default form but i can't find a way to modify the specific form. This page looks like this :

The content of specific page calls a shortcode `[tc_cart]` .

[image]

Is there any way to change the "Buyer Info" for example to "Custom Information"?

I am reading the [docs](https://tickera.com/tickera-documentation/front-end/) but i can't seem find something relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit Buyer Info form by making changes to this file:

```
tickera\includes\templates\shortcode-cart-contents.php
```

Comment: I guess this will get reset when plugin gets updated right? Can i do something so it overwrites it everytime?

Comment: Yes, you are right. You can overwite it manually after each plugin update, I don't have another idea.